# Visual Studio 2017, no drop down to change load/focus/onmove

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed the latest version of Visual Studio and do not know what this bar is called or how to bring it back.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/MeU0B]

Comment: which bar do you mean?

Comment: The bar that would allow you to change from Form1_Load to Form1_OnFocus or anything else.  Couldn't find the exact picture of what I'm talking about, but normally below the Form1.vb tab there are combo-boxes that you can change for different functions.

Comment: ok, you mean the dropdown to select classes, methods?

Comment: Correct!  How do I get those drop downs back?

Answer (score 2):

This is called the Navigation Bar.  It can be found under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic (for VB) -> General.

Each language has it's own value for a collection of common settings (including this one), and different languages pick different defaults.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  I didn't know what to call it and couldn't search for it haha.  Thanks